# Terminal doesnt support range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Tags: c++

When I compile from terminal

```cpp
vector < vector < int > > state(graph.size());
for(auto& st : state)
        st = vector<int>((1 << graph.size()) - 1, INT_MAX);
```

it shows the `error range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

How can i change it so it will compile, or how to add this `-std=c++11` on windows 10?

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` to your compile string (for MinGW)... Or for VS `/std:c++11` (VS2017 or later).

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Most compilers now have a default standard above C++11.

Comment: Why don’t you follow the instructions in the error message?

Comment: I suspect he is using `gcc/g++` otherwise he would not receive the `-std=gnu++11` suggestion.

Comment: i am using, g++

Comment: I always try to understand the reason for the massive amount of time people spend trying to cram Linux/Unix originated software, like gcc, into an alien operating system that wasn't designed to run Linux/Unix-originated code. Even experienced developers will often have these kinds of difficulties, not to speak of people who are new to C++. Most of the time it will take much less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get a fully working, fully configured, modern C++ compiler. It took me just an hour and a half, last time. How much time did you already spend on this?

Comment: Well, actually, the current standard is not C++11, and not C++14, but C++17, so perhaps you should check if you could update to the latest version supported by your compiler. *Much* has changed since 1998...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Environments like [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) make this dead easy, really. Just like Wine makes it easy to run Windows executables on Linux. Again, much has changed since the early days... and there are usually other circumstances that make a change of OS, or dual-boot, the less attractive, or non-viable solution.

Comment: @theo: You are using g++... how are you invoking it? And what hinders you from adding `-std=c++11` to that invocation as the error message suggested?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I personally prefer Linux, obviously I guess, but it's very easy to setup a gcc enviroment in Windows these days, there are reasons to do this, like having to work with Win32 API you'd want gcc compiler, because, well, MSVC is a pile of steaming... you know what.

Comment: i was looking from tutorials how to run c++ to windows 10 cmd and followed what the told.